# Download a file in background without opening browser with Intent

Tags: android, url, download

```
try {

    String url = "MY URL"
    i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    view.openDownloadIntent(i); // startsActivity
}
catch (NullPointerException e) {
    view.showMissingDocumentMessage("Failed");
}
```

This obviously opens a browser with the URL and goes immedtiatly to a downloading task. It works, but it's interruptive and should happen in the background.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Are you just want to download file in background ?

Comment: yup. It's a pdf

Comment: Download it yourself, using `HttpUrlConnection` or any number of better HTTP client libraries (e.g., OkHttp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simply `DownloadManager` for this task,

> The DownloadManager is a system service that handles long-running
>   HTTP downloads.  Clients may request that a URI be downloaded to a
>   particular destination file.  The download manager will conduct the
>   download in the background,  taking care of HTTP interactions and
>   retrying downloads after failures or across connectivity changes and
>   system reboots.

For example,

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

                request.setTitle("Downloading...");  //set title for notification in status_bar
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);  //flag for if you want to show notification in status or not

                //String nameOfFile = "YourFileName.pdf";    //if you want to give file_name manually

                String nameOfFile = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, null, MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url)); //fetching name of file and type from server

                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + yourAppFolder);       // location, where to download file in external directory
                if (!f.exists()) {
                    f.mkdirs();
                }
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(yourAppFolder, nameOfFile);
                DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

And you also have to add `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in your `AndroidManifest` file that is,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Approve it, if it helps you.

Comment: E/MMSDK-HttpUtils <17830:1515265537522>: Error occurred when trying to get response content.

Comment: Is your `url` a webpage or direct link for downloading ?

Comment: direct link, either returns a pdf or docx

Comment: May I check your link ?

Comment: Afraid not. I'll look into another solution

Comment: I am very confused because, I am using this code and it is working perfectaly.

Comment: It's a storage issue, but I think it seems to be working.